# Serilog best practices with exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, logging, serilog

I use Serilog for diagnostics in my .NET Core 5 console application. I can't decide the best logging semantics in conjunction with exception handling. For example, suppose I perform an operation that requires a file to exist. If that file doesn't exist, I throw an exception for flow-control reasons (I need to unwind to properly exit the application). But where and how do I log this? I can think of a few options:

First option - Log before I throw:

```cs
if (!File.Exists(myFilePath)) {
  _logger.Error("The file does not exist: {File}", myFilePath);
  throw new ArgumentException("File does not exist", nameof(myFilePath));
}
```

Second option - Log the exception when its caught:

```cs
try {
  if (!File.Exists(myFilePath)) {
    throw new ArgumentException("File does not exist", nameof(myFilePath));
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
  _logger.Error(e, "An Exception");
}
```

Code-wise, I like the second option best. As far as the descriptive strings themselves, I'm not repeating myself. However, I feel like the information is going to be communicated in different ways. I am not sure what the output of the second option looks like: Is it going to be structured? It's missing the original log string from the first option.

Which way is best? Are there other options I should be considering?

Comment: Serilog (and structured logging) has special property for exceptions, which is also why there is an overload of the logging methods that takes the exception as the first argument. It will be structured and contain all the message, stack trace, exception properties plus anything you log in addition to it in that same call. In my opinion (and based on my usage personally and professionally) the second choice is "correct", but that doesn't meant you can't log it both places (though perhaps verbose/debug in the first case, depending)

Comment: The second form (logging when caught) likely has more context about the operation as well. Assuming the throw site is an abstracted, generic piece of code (for example some tool just for reading a file for any old reason) it probably doesn't have enough info to make the log message meaningful. By logging when caught you can add additional info/properties in the message you log with it

Comment: For additional context: The context is code that is responsible for loading configuration. So it's at least aware that the file I'm loading is a YAML config, for example, and that it isn't there. I'm not seeing how the structured variable `{File}` gets put into the exception when its thrown. When I log the exception in the 2nd form, it won't know what "File" is, right?

Comment: OK yeah I missed that. You are correct. But if you use a more meaningful exception (FileNotFound or a custom type) that becomes a property in the exception which then would get logged when caught. OR since you know the file name when it's caught you add it to the log message with the exception `logger.Error(e, "File {File} does not exist", myFilePath)`

Comment: So is Serilog encouraging proper exception types, with attributes that map to data output in the log line itself? Then I can say, for example, `MyFileException.Filename` attribute maps to `{File}` in the structured output string? Then I do... `_logger.Error(ex, "Could not load: {File}", ex.Filename)`?

Answer (score 3):

I've grappled with this question before, and here's where I landed. Repeating yourself might not be an issue in practice: there are two events being captured, 1) a problem with the configuration file, and 2) an unhandled exception/application exit.

They're related, and they overlap a little, but they're not the same thing.

Imagine reading the events like this:

```
[ERR] Could not open configuration, the file ./foo.config does not exist
[FTL] An unhandled exception occurred, exiting the application
System.ArgumentException: The file ./foo.config does not exist
 at YourApp.OpenConfig(string filename)
 at ...
```

The first event: what went wrong? Why was the file being opened in the first place? This is the place to capture all of the detailed context.

The second event: why did the app exit? Since no higher-level handler could deal with the exception - blat, here it all is in the log.